# Open a different Shiny application by clicking link in a Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I am building my first Shiny app and have been struggling with one issue that I am not even sure if it is possible to do.

I want to allow a user to click a link (or select something or click a button; some user action), and after this I want another Shiny app to be open in front of the user (the previous one might be shut down; I no longer care about it). To put it in other words, I want to make something like the following work:

```
if(input$datasetlist == "cars"){
    runApp("C:/.../readdata")
  }
```

Of course, trying this naive code returns a warning:

```
Error in startServer("0.0.0.0", port, httpuvCallbacks) : 
Failed to create server
```

What is the correct approach for this, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a way to do this now in Shiny natively, but you might be interested in [Shiny Server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/). It allows you to host multiple applications concurrently. It will manage the startup and shutdown of apps based on whether or not they're being used.

So you could just host all your apps in Shiny Server, then provide regular links (`a(href="/anotherApp")`) to allow users to navigate between apps.